# problem with refreshing div

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

I have a div as follows:
one

```
var a = document.getElementById("xyz") ;
alert(a); //prints one
var b = document.getElementById("xyz").innerHTML ="two" ;
alert(b);  //prints two
```

But my text "two" is not reflected in UI ,How div text is not getting reflected on UI.Is there any means by which i can forcefully refresh the div.The div is not a normal div .There is some jquery plugin that converts div into tooltip of a anchor.so that when i hover mouse over anchor i can see the tooltip

EDIT:Here is how title is attached to tooltip

```
<a alt="" class="tooltipcls"
 style="background: transparent url(xyz.gif)  bla bla bla; 
 title="#idofdiv" href="javascript:void(0);"
 dojoAttachPoint="abc"
 dojoAttachEvent="onmouseover:_populatetooltip"
 ></a>
<div dojoAttachPoint="aksabc1" id="idofdiv" style="display: none; position: absolute;">pop
up content here </div>
```

See how title is attached to a div.I run a their script and tool tip gets associated with the anchor

Comment: if you're using jQuery, why are you coding regular js?

Comment: am using dojo actually, but the tooltip thing is coded in jquery, its already being developed by someone,so whenever i want to use tool tip i need to appaly a css class to anchor tag and in its title i have to give title="#divid"  where divid = xyz

Comment: are you sure `alert(a);` gives you `one`. Because either you will get `[object]` or you will get nothing at all. In any case do what @RabidFire is saying. That will fix it.

Comment: this si my dummy code, this was just a example.

Comment: You might find it useful to share an example via http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is **case-sensitive**. It should be `getElementById`. Although, that might not be the answer you're looking for.

---

**EDIT:** The problem is *probably* (since you're not showing us your complete code) that your tooltips plugin is grabbing the `div`'s text when you initialize the plugin. So, basically, you can call that function again:

```
document.getElementById('xyz').innerHTML = "two";
$('.tooltip').tooltip(); // The code that initializes your plugin
```

Again, not very optimal or anything. We don't have enough code to work with. :(

Comment: am not getiing what is $('.tooltip').tooltip().Am only familiar with dojo and js , i dont know jquery

Comment: am sorry, I cant post the original code  as its against my company policies.The have used modifiled this jquery plugin http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Tooltip

Comment: Basically, `$("#enter_your_id_selector_here").tooltip();` - In your sample case, it would be `$("#xyz").tooltip();` - Try this and see if it works. If not, create a better dummy implementation on http://www.jsfiddle.net without violating your company policies.

Comment: @rabidFire: i just added some more description

Answer (score 0):

**The "B" and the "I" must be capitalized.**

Javascript is a case-sensitive language. Javascript functions are generally spelled using [lower camel case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case), the method is called [getElementyById](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Document.getElementById).

This is from [W3C Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_guidelines.asp):

> A function named "myfunction" is not the same as "myFunction" and a variable named "myVar" is not the same as "myvar".
>
> JavaScript is case sensitive - therefore watch your capitalization closely when you create or call variables, objects and functions.

Comment: this is just a sample code. actual code doesnot have any such errors

Answer (score 0):

you can use following Jquery function to change inner text of div

```
  $("div#xyz").html('two');
```